# Visual Studio 2019 IDE Warnings about String.Format Parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

Our team upgraded a large project developed using Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2019.
One of the team members uses the `String.Format(String, Object[])` and passes an array of objects to the method while the rest of the team uses the `String.Format` method by passing the objects as individual arguments.

This was just a matter of style preference when developing in Visual Studio 2010; but in Visual Studio 2019, any place that uses the `String.Format(String, Object[])` that is passed an array is causing IDE warnings to appear.

Since the project is large, the number of these bogus warnings is numerous and going through the code to "fix" something that isn't broken is not preferable; however, these warnings do hide cases where the String format incorrectly matches the parameters (causing a runtime error).

Stranger yet, there are cases where these lines of code actually do throw String.Format exceptions if the machine running the application is not using .NET Framework 4.8. This doesn't make sense to me because this version of the String.Format method has been around since WELL before 4.8.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

Notice how there are 2 warnings on line 9 about the number of arguments passed to the String.Format method not matching the number expected in the format.

While on line 12 there are no warnings: because the String.Format method is being passed individual argument parameters instead of an array.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is causing problems using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Version 4.8? Or have a suggestion on how to correct this problem (preferably one that doesn't require modifying every line of code the one team member used their style of calling the String.Format method).

[image]

**Edit:**
Update, upon playing with this a bit more, I discovered that if the array is not declared inline (it is declared before hand), there are no errors. This worked when passing an array of strings and an array of objects.

This just makes the IDE warning even more bizarre....

[image]

Comment: You could globally suppress the warning (in C# this action is offered inline in the code helpers, I'm not sure about VM.)  (Pedantic point: the `params` form still passes an array... the compiler adds the construction for you.)

Comment: @Richard, I considered this; however, like I said, there are cases where this warning is useful in avoiding run time problems. It is a very useful warning when it is appropriately use...in this case it is inappropriate because it's fine (if I remove the {} making the array, and just pass the items as arguments it's fine)

Comment: @HansPassant, we aren't using interpolated strings. The amount of work it would take to change String.Format into Interpolated Strings is infeasible in a project of this size. The String.Format method uses the composite formatting feature to convert the value of one or more expressions to their string representations & embed them in a string. Since the String.Format args parameter is marked with the System.ParamArrayAttribute attribute, you can pass the objects to the method as individual arguments or as an Object array. It should not be necessary worry about the particular overload to call.